# Acute triangulation

Tags: discrete-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra

Assume that $S$ is a finite 2-dimensional simplicial complex equipped with a metric $d$
such that each triangle is isometric to a plane triangle (so $(S,d)$ is a polyhedral space).

> *Is it possible to subdivide the triangulation of $S$ so that it will have acute triangles only?*

**Comments:**

- It is well known that any triangle admits a triangulation with only acute triangels; one can see the proof in the following picture. But I do not see a way to fit such triangulations together. 
  [image]
- Such a triangulation would be useful in the proof of Zalgaller's theorem: *any n-dimensional polyhedral space admits a length-preserving piecewise linear map to $\mathbb R^n$*. Well, it would help only if $n=2$, for larger $n$, we should say that a simplex is acute if it contains its circumcenter.

Comment: Related though you are probably aware of it: It is shown in

[Kopczynski, Pak, Przytycki, Acute triangulations of polyhedra and $\mathbb{R}^n$][http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~pprzytyc/combinatorica.pdf]

that the 4-cube and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge 5$ do not admit acute triangulations.
Where acute means in their sense that all dihedral angles are smaller than 90°.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a theorem in Y. D. Burago, V. A. Zallgaller, "Polyhedral embedding of a net" (Russian), Vestnik Leningrad. Univ., 15 (1960), 66–80, which says that any 2-dimensional polyhedral surface has an acute triangulation.

Another proof for this theorem can be found in ["Acute and nonobtuse triangulations of polyhedral surfaces"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566980800173X) by S. Saraf. Moreover they show that any polyhedral subdivision can be further refined into a non-obtuse sub-triangulation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was surprised that acute triangulations are so popular. Is anything known in the higher dimensional case?
(acute simplex = simplex which contains its circumcenter.)

Comment: I have no idea. I think people in discrete geometry call this a "well centered mesh", but I haven't been able to find anything relevant. I know of the reference above from Igor Pak's book and as it was mentioned in the comments, Pak has investigated acute triangulations in the sense of acute dihedral angles.

Comment: Saraf's paper for free:
http://web.mit.edu/shibs/www/acute.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @Gjergji's answer: there are also algorithms to compute such things. See, for example,[Erten and Ungor, CCCG 2007](http://cccg.ca/proceedings/2007/09a2.pdf) and references therein.